# Python virtual env activation\creation problems

Tags: python, python-venv

I am trying to create a virtual env in windowns 10 on the powershell and the system dont allow me. I get this error: File C:\Users\FJSR\env\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
How I can create a virtual env for my projects without compromise my OS security?

Comment: Did you try python -m venv venv on a cmd-shell?

Comment: first of just the creation of a venv won't compromise the security, second, depending on what IDE You use, the IDE may have an option for creating the venv for You

Comment: yes, I tried and get the same error. I just donwload the venv packges of ATOM. I tried in Git bash and i get this error:                                                     FJSR@DESKTOP-NG50VMM MINGW64 ~
$ python -m venv botenv/

FJSR@DESKTOP-NG50VMM MINGW64 ~
$ source botenv/bin/activate
bash: botenv/bin/activate: No such file or directory    I just began working with Git